# Why is List(T).Clear O(N)?

Tags: .net, list, performance, big-o

According to [the MSDN documentation on the `List<T>.Clear` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a.aspx):

> This method is an O(n) operation,
>   where n is Count.

Why O(n)? I ask because I would assume that clearing a `List<T>` could be accomplished simply by allocating a new `T[]` array internally. No other class could have a reference to this array, so I fail to see the harm in this approach.

Now, maybe this is a stupid question... is allocating a `T[]` array itself O(n)? For some reason I would not have thought so; but maybe it is (is my lack of a C.S. degree showing right now?). If so, I suppose that would explain it since, according to the same documentation quoted above, the capacity of the list remains unchanged, which means an array of equal size would need to be constructed.

(Then again, this doesn't seem like it could be the correct explanation, as then the documentation should have said "where n is *Capacity*"—**not** `Count`*).

I just *suspect* that this method, rather than allocating a new array, zeroes out all elements of the current one; and I'm curious to know why this would be.

<sub>*Hans Passant pointed out in a comment to [LukeH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798910/why-is-listt-clear-on/4798964#4798964) that the docs are correct. `Clear` only zeroes out the elements that have been set in the `List<T>`; it does not need to "re-zero" all the elements past those.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the current implementation just calls [`Array.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx) on its internal `T[]` array, and `Array.Clear` is an O(n) process. (As Hans points out in the comments, the MSDN docs are correct that the `n` in this case is the list's [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx), not its [`Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx).)

But, even if it did just allocate a new `T[]` array internally, that would still be an O(n) process because allocating an array of size `n` involves initialising all `n` elements to their zero/null/default state.

Of course, there's nothing to stop some sort of internal trickery where the array could be initialised with length 0 or 42 or whatever and then auto-expanded again on-the-fly as required, amortising the overall O(n) cost.

Comment: Ha, oh right. Totally foolish of me to have neglected that fact (I *did* know that... or anyway, I thought I did)!

Comment: @LukeH, Dan Tao: But it doesn't have to allocate a new array of length `n`; it could just allocate an empty array.

Comment: @Luke: But **wait**: then since `Capacity` remains unchanged (according to the docs), shouldn't it be O(n) where n is *Capacity*?

Comment: @Jason: The only issue there is that the docs say `Capacity` will stay the same. If your argument is that this shouldn't be the case, I suppose I might agree with that. But that seems more subjective.

Comment: @Jason: Well, I guess it does if the documentation states that `Capacity` remains unchanged. But that is utterly retarded.

Comment: @Dan Tao: Yes, that is what I'm saying.

Comment: @Dan, @Jason: The capacity *is* the size of the internal array.

Comment: @LukeH: Growing the array is `O(log n)`, not `O(n)` as your edit implies (assuming a doubling of the size when a regrowth is needed).

Comment: @LukeH: Yes, I get that the `Capacity` is the size of the internal array. The question is why preserve it on a call to `Clear`?

Comment: @Luke: Yeah, the capacity is the size of the internal *array*; but the docs say `Clear` is O(n) where n is **`Count`**. This threw me off initially; but it's apparent to me your answer is correct. I think the docs are incorrect, actually.

Comment: It passes this._size to the Array.Clear() for the *length* argument.

Comment: @Dan: Capacity is always Count+X, O(n+x) == O(n). A little sloppy at worst, but you can't really come up with an expression for X

Comment: @Henk: But X is not constant. If the `List<T>` cleared all elements in the array (which @Hans has already pointed out it does *not* —I'm just saying if it *did*) then clearing a 1-element list with a capacity of 10 would certainly not be the same as clearing a 1-element list with a capacity of 10,000.

Comment: @Dan: That level of accuracy is not what O(n) is meant for. The _size does indeed clear it up, but even a Clear(Capacity) would still be O(Count). O(n*C) == O(n) even if C = 10^10

Comment: @Henk: I still think you're mistaken. Let's say clearing a `List<T>` zeroed out **all** elements in the internal array (again: you and I both realize it does not; this is purely hypothetical). Then to say that clearing is O(n) where n is Count would be wrong. It would imply that the cost of clearing the list rises with the growth of Count. But it rises with the growth of Capacity. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Jason: Since resizing the array involves allocating a new array and then copying the existing elements into the new array it would be O(n) at best, probably O(n log n). I don't see how it could be as low as O(log n). (And anybody correct me if I'm wrong on this; Big-O stuff really isn't my forté.)

Comment: @Henk: I mean, forget `List<T>` for a sec; let's just say I have some algorithm with two inputs, X and Y where Y is always greater than or equal to X. It sounds to me like you're saying if the algorithm grows linearly with Y then it can be said to be O(n) where n is X. Isn't that just inaccurate?

Comment: @Dan: In that hypoth case the spec O(Capacity) would have been better, but O(Count) would not have been totally wrong.

Comment: @LukeH: You're right, I forgot about the copying. Basically there are `O(log n)` reallocations when you use a double-on-resize strategy. Thus it looks something like `n / 2 + n / 4 + n / 8 + ... ` = `O(n)`

Answer (score 6):

Because the implementation of `List<T>.Clear()` calls `Array.Clear()` on the list's backign array, and per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx) that method sets all of the elements of that array to `null`.

I would guess that the reason why the existing array is cleared instead of a new one being created is that the .NET team determined that it was more efficient to clear an existing array instead of allocating a new one. Allocating a new array also takes time/memory so it's a tradeoff that tries to optimize for the common usage scenarios.

Comment: Could you offer any thoughts on why the implementation of `List<T>.Clear` calls `Array.Clear`, though? Memory savings?

Comment: Seems only half an answer. Why does it call Array.Clear() ? Ie is there some situation where that is useful?

Comment: @Henk @Dan - it doesn't require any new allocations (presumably you intend to re-use the list if you are calling Clear), and it releases the current objects for garbage collection

Comment: @Marc: but the objects would be released for garbage collection anyway. As the OP points out, there would be no other references to the old array, so it could be GC'ed just fine. So unless there's more to it, it comes down to performing an O(n) operation to avoid an allocation.

Comment: I had to give it some time - as @LukeH points out you have to zero the new one anyway, and Clear() is for when you want to keep Capacity. And the internal array _might_ have been promoted to gen 1+, and then keeping it is cheaper than a new one. In gen 0 the costs would be about the same.

Comment: @Marc: that's what I said. The key is, as @LukeH's answer points out, that even if we allocated a new array, we'd have to initialize it, which is also O(n). This answer doesn't mention *why* the allocation isn't worth using, just that the implementers of .NET chose to do a O(n) operation in order to avoid an allocation (which the OP and many others often think of as being constant time)

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>.Clear()` calls `Array.Clear()` as seen here:

```
public virtual void Clear()
{
    if (this._size > 0)
    {
        Array.Clear(this._items, 0, this._size);
        this._size = 0;
    }
    this._version++;
}
```

In turn, `Array.Clear()` calls down to an external function which will zero the elements of the array which is O(n):

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), SecuritySafeCritical, ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
public static extern void Clear(Array array, int index, int length);
```

Comment: `Array.Clear` does not initialize a new array. It zeroes out the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this question from a different side, which is not answered here. I was thinking it should be O(1) because no allocation is required, only changing the Count flag/pointer, so resetting every element (no longer accessible) to the default value looked wasteful, and I wondered why it would be done.

The answer of course is that this would work for ValueTypes/structs, but not for classes. The latter should be de-referenced, even from the List's private array, or else they won't be eligible for garbage collection.

Note n is Count, not Capacity, because the List is always keeping a contract that, whatever elements are not accessible, refer to no value too. So the elements between Count and Capacity, either they were never set, or they were already re-set when removed.

However for structs this resetting is wasteful, Clear() could be O(1) in that case. So there is space in the standard library (now that Microsoft is improving performance of C#) for an IList where T:struct with all the features of List<> plus a O(1) Clear() implementation.

On the OP's proposal of allocating a new private array: first you already have that option, if that's what you want, just new the List itself. Second as LukeH says, allocating is O(n) because it implies initialization/resetting. And third, it'd be very tricky to compare the O(n) of traversing an already allocated list/array, with whatever time a new allocation (and de-allocation) entails.

Answer (score -1):

`List<T>` lists hold some objects. Allocating a new `List<T>` does not get rid of the objects in the old list, hence it is not a `clear` operation.

The operation `clear` does a linear one-time pass through the list, clearing all the elements one by one. Since there are `n` elements, this takes `O(n)` time.

Allocating a `T[]` depends on whether a size is specified. If a size is specified, then memory has to be set aside for each element, or at least each pointer for that element. Thus that would take `O(n)`. However, if we're simply initializing a pointer for `T[]`, that would take `O(1)` time.

P.S. CS degree does not automatically mean you know (or remember) this stuff... sad, but, true. Lack of CS degree is not detrimental at all.

Comment: "Allocating a new List<T> does not get rid of the objects ..." - Yes it does. By dropping the old list the refs to the elements are lost.

Comment: If there were no other references to those objects, then they'd be GC'd. If there *were* references, that's another story. But either way allocating a new array would achieve the same effect as zeroing out the elements.